# Cannot step into system call source code

Tags: unix, gdb, systems-programming

I have compiled my freebsd libc source with -g option, so that now I can step in into libc functions.

But I am having trouble stepping into system calls code. I have compiled the freebsd kernel source code with -g. On setting the breakpoint, gdb informs about breakpoint on .S files. On hitting the breakpoint, gdb is unable to step into the syscall source code.

Also, I have tried: gdb$catch syscall open

but this is also not working.

Can you please suggest something?

Thanks.

Comment: Debugging on Linux is implemented via the `ptrace(2)` system call; `ptrace` can _only_ inspect and stop processes running in userspace. I would expect that FreeBSD's process debugging mechanism is similar, and only designed to work on userspace processes: because the OS kernel will acquire and release locks as well as respond to interrupts quickly, designing the kernel to allow full-featured debugging from userspace seems very unlikely.

Comment: Hi Sarnold, Thanks for your comment. If user-space debugging is not possible then can kdb/kgdb serve the purpose?

Comment: it's been years since I've looked into kdb/kgdb, probably things have drastically changed. :) But perhaps [this message about stack dumps](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2009-March/004191.html) will be a good starting point?

Answer (score 9):

You appear to have fundamental lack of understanding of how UNIX systems work.

Think about it. Suppose you were able to step into the kernel function that implements a system call, say `sys_open`. So now you are looking at the kernel source for `sys_open` in the debugger. The question is: is the kernel running at that point, or is it stopped. Since you will want to do something like `next` in the debugger, let's assume the kernel *is* stopped.

So now you press the `n` key, and what happens?

Normally, the *kernel* will react to an interrupt raised by the keyboard, figure out which key was pressed, and send that key to the right process (the one that is blocked in `read(2)` from the terminal that has control of the keyboard).

But *your* kernel is *stopped*, so no key press for you.

Conclusion: debugging the kernel via debugger that is running on that same machine is impossible.

In fact, when people debug the kernel, they usually do it by running debugger on *another* machine (this is called remote debugging).

If you really want to step into kernel, the easiest way to do that is with [UML](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/).

After you've played with UML and understand how the userspace/kernel interface works and interacts, you can try `kgdb`, though the setup is usually a bit more complicated. You don't actually have to have a separate machine for this, you could use VMWare or VirtualPC, or VirtualBox.

Comment: Your "debugging the kernel via debugger that is running on that same machine is impossible" conclusion is AFAIK applying only to kgdb on Linux. UML is also a Linux specific solution. There is a port of kgdb to FreeBSD but FreeBSD kernel can be debugged locally with ddb, just like Solaris can be with kmdb.

Comment: You explanation about the reason why a kernel debugger can't work is flawed. A kernel is not a single threaded program, and not even a multi-threaded one either. A kernel is code executed in a privileged context. Many kernel threads can run this code concurrently so a breakpoint affecting an instruction executed by one of them has no compelling reason to suddenly "stop the kernel", i.e. stop every other kernel thread.

Answer (score 3):

As Employed Russian already stated, gdb being in userland cannot inspect anything running in the kernel.

However, nothing prevents to implement a debugger in the kernel itself. In such case, it is possible to set breakpoints and run kernel code step by step from a local debugging session (console). With FreeBSD, such a debugger is available as [ddb](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ddb&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%209-current&format=html).

Some limitations would be the lack of connection between your gdb and ddb sessions and I'm unsure source level debugging (-g) is available for kernel code under FreeBSD/ddb.

An alternate and much less intrusive way to 'debug' the kernel from userland would be to use [dtrace](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dtrace&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports).